# Some pages are not securely loaded using https

Tags: boonex-dolphin

We have migrated the website from http to https. Also we have installed ssl certification for the website. The website is dolphin 7.1

The problem is when we load the website the pages are loading using https but the lock symbol is not coming.

When I load the site in firefox It shows "This website does not supply identity information. Your connection to this website is only partially encrypted, and does not prevent eavesdropping."

When I load the site in chrome browser it shows lock symbol for some webpages but not for all.
The issue is the site refer the insecured content such as the content are from http websites.

Please help me and tell me the solution for this issue.

Thanks in advance.